# How to use TTL property of mongodb from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, ttl

I want the collection i am inserting into mongodb to expire after a certain amount of time.

```
var db = mongo.GetDatabase("weatherdb");
using (mongo.RequestStart(db))
{
    var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("weatherdatanew24")
        .EnsureIndex("Date" -> 1, "expireAfterSeconds" -> 120);
}
```

but the ensureINdex part is not working i think.
Help please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var db = mongo.GetDatabase("weatherdb");
using (mongo.RequestStart(db))
{
    var keys = IndexKeys.Ascending("Date");
    var options = IndexOptions.SetTimeToLive(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
    var collection = db.GetCollection("weatherdatanew24").EnsureIndex(keys, options);
}
```

Comment: i did this but it gives error saying cannot assign void to implicitly typed local variable